# &amp; is always being decoded (which I don't want) using HtmlOutput or HtmlTemplate

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

I've created a script one or two years ago, which exports all strings for Android and iOS.
It shows a dialog with textareas for each language with the full strings file in the textarea.
It always worked fine until UiApp was removed.

So right now I've tried using HtmlService and HtmlTemplate. Both result in `&amp;` being converted to &.

HtmlOutput I'm using this code:

```
    var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput().setWidth(800).setHeight(600);
    htmlOutput.append('<textarea style="width: 100%; height: 100px;" id="' + id + '">' + content + '</textarea>');
```

This produces a textarea with for example this:

```
<string name="terms">Terms & Privacy</string>
```

---

For HtmlTemplate I've tried:

```
    var templateString = '<textarea style="width: 100%; height: 100px;" id="' + ("export_" + i) + '">' + '<?!=' + texts[i] + '?>' + '</textarea>';
//  Or this one without Force-printing scriptlets
//  var templateString = '<textarea style="width: 100%; height: 100px;" id="' + ("export_" + i) + '">' + texts[i] + '</textarea>';
    HtmlService.createTemplate(templateString).evaluate().setWidth(800).setHeight(600);
```

I tried to use Force-printing scriptlets which gives an even weirder output:

```
Terms & Privacy
```

It doesn't even give the `<string>` tags around it. When I leave the Force-printing scriptlets away it gives the same result as HtmlOutput.

---

#### Some extra info

Before I'm exporting it using these methods I'm making sure every string is being converted so it will be the correct output for Android and iOS. For example I'm using this piece of code to convert a string:

```
var text = o.texts[textIndex];
text = text.replace(/&/g, "&amp;");
'<string name="' + identifier + '">' + text + '</string>' + "\n";
```

This is of course not all, but just to give an idea how the script works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution**

You can utilize the `appendUntrusted()` method to return HTML without being parsed. Everything you append to output via this method will not be treated as markup (think of it as setting `textContent` property).

**Sample**

```
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput().setWidth(800).setHeight(600);
      htmlOutput.append('<textarea style="width: 100%; height: 100px;" id="' + id + '">');
      htmlOutput.appendUntrusted(content);
      htmlOutput.append('</textarea>');
```

**Output**

And this is a sample output (I used `'&amp; &amp; and two'` as `content`)

[image]

**Useful links**

1. `appendUntrusted()` method [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#appendUntrusted(String));

Comment: Hmm that could work! I know the method, but never thought of splitting up the appends between open and closing tags. I'll try it when I get home!

Comment: Hi Kevin! Hope this helps - please, see the update to the answer - have I understood you correctly and this is the output you want? Btw, agreed, it's not that obvious to split the html markup, but since parsing is done only after the `HtmlOutput` is constructed, `append` method can be split as much as needed

Comment: I've tried your code and it works exactly like I wanted it! I've accepted your answer

Comment: Great! Glad I could help - not that this is a primary use of `appendUntrusted()` but since the `HtmlOutput` migration it is probably the only method easily mixing up the markup and plain text

Comment: Yeah, I can imagine it was meant for something else haha. But this was exactly the thing I was missing. Just pasting plain text in between the html tags. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try replacing `&` with literal `&amp;`:

```
text = text.replace(/&/g, "&amp;amp;");
```

```html
<textarea><string>Terms &amp;amp;Privacy</string></textarea>
<textarea></textarea>
<script>
document.querySelectorAll('textarea')[1].innerText = "Terms &amp; Conditions"
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah that could work. But I prefer if there is a solution which just puts unedited text into the textarea. I'll wait for some more answers which hopefully give me this solution and otherwise I'll accept your answer!

Comment: @Kevin I don't think this is a specific issue with gas.  The unedited text is already there. But, This is how html is interpreted by the browser. `&amp;` is interpreted as `&` and they need to be escaped. Alternatively, you can use JavaScript to add  plain text

Comment: I understand when converting a string to html it decodes the `&amp;`. But several other things I've tried won't work as well. I've tried the script as well, because that should've worked in last case scenario, but it didn't. The problem is, when I try a hardcoded text it properly shows the `&amp;` but as soon as I put a variable in there, it no longer works. And if I print the code, all looks good, but as soon as the real html is shown, it just shows &. But Oleg's answer was what I was looking for. Just pasting the plain text in between the textarea tags. But thanks for your answer!